# Cloned SSD wont boot Debian

Tags: linux, debian, grub, clonezilla

I had a smaller M2 SSD which I've cloned with clonezilla to a 1 tb M2 SSD.
This contained a dual boot with Windows 10 and Debian.

At first it didn't boot Windows or Debian.

After some restarting I used the Windows repair function to at least get into Windows.

Now Debian (Grub?) is still broken.

I used a live Debian USB drive to try and run Bootrepair but this didn't work.

I do have the [pastebin here](https://paste.debian.net/hidden/d031a31f/). If I'm not mistaken I do see a Linux filesystem on nvme0n1p4 but I couldn't mount it. I got the error message "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock".

Now I'm stuck. Please help me boot into my beloved Debian once again so I can leave Windows behind.

Comment: I don't like the message "According to the info in the boot sector, nvme0n1p3 
starts at sector 577536. But according to the info from fdisk, nvme0n1p3 starts at sector 575735". It seems like the cloning process was badly done. How did you do it?

Comment: I cloned it using clonezilla, didn’t see error messages of any kind.

Comment: Try perhaps [Super Grub2](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).